# .Net Write continuously data to the disk in different files

Tags: c#, .net, filestream, disk, hard-drive

We have an application that extract data from several hardware devices. Each device's data should be stored in a different file.

Currently we have one FileStream by file and doing a write when a data comes and that's it.

We have a lot of data coming in, the disk is struggling with an HDD(not a SSD), I guess because the flash is faster, but also because we do not have to jump to different file places all the time.

Some metrics for the default case: 400 different data source(each should have his own file) and we receive ~50KB/s for each data(so 20MB/s). Each data source acquisition is running concurrently and at total we are using ~6% of the CPU.

Is there a way to organize the flush to the disk in order to ensure the better flow?

We will also consider improving the hardware, but it's not really the subject here, since it's a good way to improve our read/write

Comment: Sounds like you need fast writing, and retrieval is allowed to be relatively slow. So why not store it in one file, or better - a database - that allows sequential writing.

Comment: Exactly. Use a database for this.

Comment: Guys, this is not the question... And even if it was the case, writing to a database could not be faster than writing to the disk, there is the communication overhead, SQL overhead and all the DBMS overhead.
And even if it was faster, it's not even an option since we have so many maintenance operation that will make us all the time we earn.

Comment: I read your question as: our disk is struggling because we have to jump all over the place to write data to it, how can we avoid that? The answer is: write it sequentially. The usual way of implementing that is: store it in a database.

Comment: Another option then: did you consider caching the data in chunks of e.g. 10 MB (x 400 data sources = 4 GB of RAM) and writing the whole buffer as soon as the block fills up? This avoids having to jump back and forth for small pieces of data.

Comment: One thought that comes to mind is to make the writing into a two step process. First, write all the streams to one file in a way that the sources can be extracted. This will limit the files be written to concurrently. Next, have a job that occasionally takes the one file and uses it to write batches of data to each file at a time. Alternately, you could also just do this all in-memory, but the holding file would allow better persistence.

Comment: Possible duplicate of / useful answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/7424315/2920343

Comment: @CompuChip We have large amount of RAM(16GB), so buffering is something we are open too, but I was hopping that playing with parameter/flush of the fileStream will allow this kind of behavior?

Comment: @NathanC We did considered that, but having to read the whole file and write it after make the initial writing much slower

Comment: My suggestion was made in the same spirit as the suggestion that  @CompuChip made. I was mainly trying to deal with the idea of data persistence. If you don't need to fully guarantee data won't be dropped, then a pure memory solution would work. If you need the persistence, you could do it mainly in memory but also have a temp file that is written to and deleted when the in-memory data is written. The file would only be used as a data source on process start-up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows and NTFS handle multiple concurrent sequential IO streams to the same disk terribly inefficiently. Probably, you are suffering from random IO. You need to schedule the IO yourself in bigger chunks.

You might also see extreme fragmentation. In such cases NTFS sometimes allocates every Nth sector to each of the N files. It is hard to believe how bad NTFS is in such scenarios.

Buffer data for each file until you have like 16MB. Then, flush it out. Do not write to multiple files at the same time. That way you have one disk seek for each 16MB segment which reduces seek overhead to near zero.